# terraform helm release and kyverno

Tags: terraform, helm3, terraform-provider-helm

I can not get `version` to work in `helm_release` for terraform against `kyverno`, I've tried "v1.7.4" and "1.74", when I leave it off it deploys `v1.7.4`, no problem.  What's it expecting as an input so the version I use is locked? https://github.com/kyverno/kyverno/tree/v1.7.4

error :

`chart "kyverno" version "v1.7.4" not found in https://kyverno.github.io/kyverno/ repository, same for "1.7.0"`

```
resource "helm_release" "kyverno" {
  name       = "kyverno"
  chart      = "kyverno"
  repository = "https://kyverno.github.io/kyverno/"
  **# version          = "v1.7.4"**
  namespace        = "kyverno"
  create_namespace = true
  values = [
    file("./manifests/kyverno/helm/values.yaml")
  ]
  set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = 1
  }
  set {
    name  = "namespace"
    value = "kyverno"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: see edit in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the official **Helm chart version, not the application version**. The way you can verify that is by first installing the Helm repo locally:

```bash
helm repo add kyverno https://kyverno.github.io/kyverno/
```

And then searching the repo:

```bash
> helm search repo kyverno
NAME                        CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
kyverno/kyverno             v2.5.4          v1.7.4      Kubernetes Native Policy Management               
kyverno/kyverno-crds        v2.0.3          v1.4.3      Kubernetes Native Policy Management CRDs          
kyverno/kyverno-policies    v2.5.5          v1.7.3      Kubernetes Pod Security Standards implemented a...
```

As you can see, you are actually looking for the chart version `v2.5.4`. The correct way to reference a chart version is without the `v`, so you want:

```
resource "helm_release" "kyverno" {
  name             = "kyverno"
  chart            = "kyverno"
  repository       = "https://kyverno.github.io/kyverno/"
  version          = "2.5.4"
  namespace        = "kyverno"
  create_namespace = true
  values = [
    file("./manifests/kyverno/helm/values.yaml")
  ]
  set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = 1
  }
  set {
    name  = "namespace"
    value = "kyverno"
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe as addition, Kyverno suggest using at least 3 replicas to guarantee HA